# Разбор json в dbxjson полученный от synapse

Tags: delphi, json, utf-8, unicode, delphi-2010

Получаю данные через Synapse в кодировке UTF8. Затем его надо прогнать через функцию StripNonJson и "засунуть" в переменную типа TJsonObject.

```
function StripNonJson(s: string): string; // Убирает лишние пробелы из json-строки
var
  ch: char;
  inString: boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  inString := false;
  for ch in s do
  begin
    if ch = '"' then
      inString := not inString;
    if TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(ch) and not inString then
      continue;
    Result := Result + ch;
  end;
end;

function MemoryStreamToString(M: TMemoryStream): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, PChar(M.Memory), M.Size div SizeOf(Char));
end;


var
  json: TJSONObject;
  // ...

begin
  // ...

  with THTTPSend.Create do
  begin
    try
      MimeType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      Document.LoadFromStream(data);
      if HTTPMethod('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post') then
      begin
        WriteLn('res=' + MemoryStreamToString(Document));
        json := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StripNonJson(MemoryStreamToString(Document))), 0) as TJSONObject;

        if Assigned(Json) then
        begin
          WriteLn('Json parsed!');
        end
        else
        begin
          WriteLn('Error parsing JSON!');
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        WriteLn('Request error: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + ' ' + ResultString);
      end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

На экран выходят крякозябры и естественно в переменной json пусто.

[image]

Я так понимаю нужно перевести Document из utf8 в родной для Delphi 2010 unicode, но не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Делфи для конвертации строк между кодировками есть класс `TEncoding`

```
function MemoryStreamToString(M: TMemoryStream): string;
begin
  Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(M.Memory, 0, M.Size);  
end;
```

Comment: в дополнение - скорее всего, для вывода в консоль (и только для него) будет нужно использовать AnsiToOEM.

Comment: @kami не нужно будет